# LibGdx : Using setInputProcessor(stage) in different classes

Tags: java, android, libgdx, processor

I am developing android game using LibGdx; for the moment, there are 2 menu screens with several buttons, a mainMenu and a gameOverMenu.
I need to use Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); in both classes but i can't... There's only one screen working.

I search a lot on the forum and i found only Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer)...

```
InputProcessor inputProcessorOne = new CustomInputProcessorOne();
InputProcessor inputProcessorTwo = new CustomInputProcessorTwo();
InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(inputProcessorOne);
inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(inputProcessorTwo);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```

I'm having trouble with it because it's used in order to have several processor in the same class.

But i just need 1 processor in two separate classes.

For the moment, i have this... But it doesn't work:

CLASS 1
`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageMainMenu);`

CLASS 2
`Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageGameOverMenu);`

EDIT :
 **@MennoGouw** 
the problem, with what i quote, is that i'd like to put Stage Object in addProcessor, not InputProcessor. 
I don't want to create my own Processor, i'd use ClickListener.
Besides i don't really need to use both processors at the same time. Indeed, these are two different screens. However, there is no clear method for InputProcessor.

Besides i don't know where i should build `InputMultiplexer` .

I'll try to be more clear,  I have : 
MyGame.java with only one method (
            `public void create() {
            mainMenuScreen = new MainMenu(this);
            //gameScreen = new MainGame(this);
            gameOverScreen = new GameOver(this);
            setScreen(mainMenuScreen);

    }`)

And GameOver.java & MainMenu.java. (the two screens)
If i put `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stageName)` in the constructor, only one of the two runs.
Else, in the show() method, it crashes.

Thanks for your time

Comment: If you want both the processors to work at the same time you should use the `InputMultiplexer` like you are doing in your code. If you need only one active you can `inputMultiplexer.clear` and add a new on whenever you like.

Comment: Please show your calls to setInputProcessor in context. You should be calling those in the respective show() methods, probably. You don't need a multiplexer for this because the stages are on different screens.

Comment: @Tenfour04 But when i use only InputProcessor in both the show() method, it works one time. ( I can launch the game, but when i'm on the GameOver screen, if i click on a button, it crashes )

Comment: You should clarify your question. When you said is doesn't work, everyone assumed you meant it doesn't accept clicks. If you can click the button, and it does something,  it's working. The bug must be in what the button is doing. Any time you have a crash, look at the stack trace in the log, which tells you exactly which method is causing the issue. And if you still need help with it, post the trace here.

Comment: Yes when i said it doesn't work, no button were active. 
With your solution, put InputProcessor in show, it works a bit :)

I'll explore what you're telling me! Thanks again

Comment: @Tenfour04 Indeed, in the show(), buttons work well. I guess the bug issue (the display alternately shows the two screens rapidly and then quit the launcher) is due to something else. I'll search. 

Thanks a lot for your help, i was stuck here for 3 days at least... Question answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the issue with `InputMultiplexer`? It is made for what you are looking for.

You could also use this piece of code to add the processers in each Stage respectively:

First setup Multiplexer in your init Game class function:

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer());
```

And later check if you have to add your input processor:

```
InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer = (InputMultiplexer) Gdx.input.getInputProcessor();
if (!inputMultiplexer.getProcessors().contains(stageMainMenu))
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(stageMainMenu);
```